# as_json with options not working in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Does `as_json()` or `to_json()` in views works with options?

```
<%- @profiles.each { |p| %>
<%= p.as_json(:only => [:name])  %>
<%- } %>
```

I can never get this to work, it always return the whole object as json.

Comment: it works just fine, what rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails 3.2.9, All I wanted is to select individual fields rather than selecting everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using Rails 3.2.9, I have copied and pasted your code into my user view and it worked just fine.

Try to create a new application with a generated profiles scaffold to see if it works properly.

Comment: yes, this is indeed working. I guess there is something wrong with my model

Answer (score 0):

if <%= p.as_json(:only => [:name])  %> returns {"profile"=>{"name"=>"profile_name"}},
You can replace with:

```
<%- @profiles.each { |p| %>
  <%= p.as_json(:only => [:name])["profile"]["name"]  %>
<%- } %>
```

Comment: good thing to know, but I want to preserve the JSON structure